# Mac often wouldn't sleep nor show screensaver

Tags: macos

If I manually ≪Menu → Sleep≫ or ≪Screensaver settings → Preview≫ it will work, but it wouldn't do sleep/screensaver with the set hotcorner nor automatically.

Every now and then I'll have this issue. How do I fix the problem or investigate what has went wrong?

---

(Its usual settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcJH5.jpg)

(Refreshing the settings (eg by toggling ≪Enable power nap while plugged into a power adapter≫) would temporary fix the problem—until it comes again.)

Answer (score 1):

Launch Terminal

```
pmset -g assertions
```

that will give you a clue as to what is stopping sleep

Comment: 'will give this a try when the issue pops up again. btw What am I supposed to look for in the output?

Comment: it  will list what is keeping the system awake so you can troubleshoot suggest you look when there is no trouble and compare to when there is